# Json Phonegap Api

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

Can someone please help me figure out how to fit this piece of javascript after the `$.each` in my  to fit my needs? My JSON array can be found in the url declared in my javascript. Any help is much appreciated!

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("http://quickcutsystem.com/quotesapp-home/?json=1",function(result){
 $.each(result, function(i, field){
 $("#output").append("Title: "+ field.title + " duration: "+field.id +" Price:"+field.price+"<br/>");
 });
 });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(result, function(i, field){
 $("#output").append(field.content);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JSON in your example, there is no need to loop through fields as it's not an array. You can just access the properties that you need, like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://quickcutsystem.com/quotesapp-home/json=1",function(result)
{
     var page = result.page;

     $("#output").append("Title: "+ page.title + " duration: "+page.id +"Price:"+page.price+"<br/>");
});
```

However there is no price in the json, you could loop through the attachments or show author details or the content etc.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! I appreciate that!